# Responsive side navigation not closing when click to another route

Tags: angular

I need help with my responsive sidebar navigation but there is an issue whereby I click the link to go to another route the sidebar navigation doesn't close. How do I fix this?
Here is the code as below for your reference:

app.component.html

```
<nav class="navigation">
        <div class="nav-bg"></div>
        <div class="page-container">
        <div class="logo-wrap"><a routerLink="/" id="logo"></a></div>
        <div class="menu-wrap">
                <a class="hamburger" (click)="isShown = !isShown" [ngClass]="{'open': isShown }" ><span></span></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links" 
            @showState
            *ngIf="isShown"[@showStag]>
            <a [@navState] href="#" class="nav-item" routerLink="/agency">Agency</a>
            <a [@navState] href="#" class="nav-item" routerLink="/work">Work</a>
            <a [@navState] href="#" class="nav-item" routerLink="/careers">Careers</a>
            <a [@navState] href="#" class="nav-item" routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';
import { App } from './app.model';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ContactService } from './app.service';
import { showStateTrigger, showStagTrigger, navListStateTrigger } from './animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [AppService, ContactService, CMSService, CMSProvider],
  animations: [
    showStateTrigger,
    showStagTrigger,
    navListStateTrigger
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  isShown = true;

  constructor(private appService: AppService, private contactService: ContactService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to put a click event on the links to set isShown to false.

```
  <ul class="nav-links" @showState *ngIf="isShown"[@showStag]>
     <a [@navState] href="#" class="nav-item" routerLink="/agency" (click)="isShown = !isShown">Agency</a>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks!! it works. However there is a new problem when I enlarge the browser now my nav disappears.